# Why does an index on a datetime column have low cardinality in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime, indexing, cardinality

I have a table with over 18M rows that is growing quickly.

I created a composite index on a datetime column (millions of unique values), intColumn 1 (with about 40k unique values, intColumn 2 (with about 3k unique values) and intColumn 3 (with 1k unique values).

The cardinality of the index ended up being 197!

I am really confused by this and wonder if I did something wrong or is there something I am missing.  This index seems useless.

Answer (score 2):

Try running `ANALYZE TABLE` and then check cardinality. Cardinality shown is just an estimate, and it is probably not correct.

Also, take a look [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10340/primary-key-index-with-a-datetime-as-first-part-of-the-compound-key-is-never-use), it might be of some help.